# Column with most repeated word in other column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like

| MyText |
| --- |
| Car, Car, Blue |
| Blue, Blue, Car |

And I would like to get one like this, using SQL because it would run in SQL Server

| MyText | mostRepeatedWord |
| --- | --- |
| Car, Car, Blue | Car |
| Blue, Blue, Car | Blue |

I was trying to use `string_split` modifying next code

```sql
    with words as (
    select value as word from 
    string_split('banana, apple, lemons, kiwi, orange, apple', ','))
    SELECT  top 1 word, count(word) as counts
    from words
    group by word
    order by counts desc
```

what returns me

| word | counts |
| --- | --- |
| apple | 2 |

But I don't know how to replace that fruits string to the values of `MyText` Column

In the case of 'car, car, blue blue' I don't care which one is returned, the top 1 and order by are in charge of selecting the first one.

Thanks

Comment: What is the most repeated word in 'car, car, blue, blue'?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Check out [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @DaleK I added more information to the question but I don't know if it enough to understand it

Answer (score 1):

You can include MyText in the result if you apply to a sub-query with string_split.

```
select MyText, ca.*
from MyTable
outer apply (
 select top 1 trim(value) as word, count(*) as counts
 from string_split(MyText, ',') s
 group by trim(value) 
 order by count(*) desc
) ca;
```

| MyText | word | counts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Car, Car, Blue | Car | 2 |
| Blue, Blue, Car | Blue | 2 |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b239ddc6d5003acb0d75f80833afc1bb)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use some *window functions* to partition each group's count and select the top 1 of each using *with ties*

```
with c as (
    select mytext, Trim(value) Word,
      Count(*) over(partition by mytext, Trim(value)) cnt
    from t
    cross apply string_split(mytext, ',')
)
select top (1) with ties  mytext, word, cnt MaxCount 
from c
group by mytext, word, cnt
order by row_number() over (partition by mytext order by cnt desc);
```

[DB Fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7e942373129e641c872068dbc498cc9d)